# Valuation ring whose unique maximal ideal and every ideal of finite height is principal

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, valuation-theory, krull-dimension, local-rings

Let $(R, \mathfrak m) $ be a valuation ring such that $\mathfrak m$ and every ideal of finite height is principal. Then is $R$ Noetherian , i.e. a discrete valuation ring ?

Comment: Have you looked at something like the valuation ring of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$? 
I'm not sure what a finite height ideal should look like, but every finite type ideal in it will be principal.

Comment: @A.Rod: In any valuation ring, finitely generated ideals are principal.

Comment: Indeed, you're right.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302341/valuation-ring-whose-maximal-ideal-and-every-ideal-of-finite-height-are-principa